# How to get the best combinations of features for a sale optimization problem?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, optimization

I have a **database of shoes items** from the same brand with many variables (features) like the size, the color or the shape. I also have the produced and sold quantity for the last years.

This is a sample of the database:

[image: Data sample]

I would like to know what are the **best combinations of features** to have the perfect shoes, i.e the shoes which will be sold the most for sure. The Ratio (last column) is the variable which gives a "score" to an item (=an combination of features). For example, the best combination can be : *construction=vulcanized + colour=brown but without width=welded*.

I am using Python to read the database and using the library Pandas. This problem can be an **optimization problem**. What are the possibilities in data science to solve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have an optimization problem the first question that you have to ask yourself is.

Can I make it a Linear Programming problem?

For python I normally use Gurobi. Here is a basic example to get started: https://www.gurobi.com/resources/food-manufacture-i/

You can also do Machine Learning with it, that is the hot topic nowadays, but if you can make it a linear programming problem you will achieve optimality.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't think it can be a linear programming problem as there are categorical variables or maybe it is possible but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestions ? Also, I agree we can use machine learning but I have no idea which algorithms I can use to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Do you know python?? @Alex